# How to get value from unserialized data

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I'm transforming my data into an array structure. Now I have the meta which already unserialized and I just need to take a specific value in meta.

Code

```
$item->meta;
            $itm['attrs'] = @unserialize($item->meta);
            $serial = @unserialize($item->meta);

            $itm['product']['attrs'] = $itm['attrs'];
            $itm['product']['serial'] = $serial['serial'];
```

Result

```
"product" => array:2 [
        "attrs" => array:1 [
          "serial" => array:1 [
            0 => array:3 [
              "id" => 848
              "text" => "12345wf"
              "trade_in" => 0
            ]
          ]
        ]
        "serial" => array:1 [
          0 => array:3 [
            "id" => 848
            "text" => "12345wf"
            "trade_in" => 0
          ]
        ]
      ]
```

Expected Result

```
"product" => array:2 [
        "attrs" => array:1 [
          "serial" => array:1 [
            0 => array:3 [
              "id" => 848
              "text" => "12345wf"
              "trade_in" => 0
            ]
          ]
        ]
        "serial" => "12345wf" 
      ]
```

I'm not sure how to get the value and pass to the object.

Comment: `$itm['product']['serial'] = $serial['serial'][0]['text'];`

Comment: it worked, but why is array 0?

Comment: because `"serial" => array:1 [  0 => array` -  its two-dimensional array